# Docopt and Classes

Tags: class, python-2.7

Ive gotten quite comfortable over the last year coding in python on an off, but I have stayed away from Classes (as in structuring my code in them) because I have not understood them.

I am now trying to get my head around what I need to change in my coding practices to take advantage of using Classes in all their glory.

I have been trying to use an example script I wrote and pipe that to a Class based version. Safe to say I am sucking bad and cant get my simple script to work. Im sure there are a myriad of this Im most likely doing incorrectly. I would really appreciate someone pointing them out to me.

I dont mind finger points and belly laughs too ^_^

**Coder After** (not working)

```
"""
Description:

This script is used to walk a directory and print out each filename and  directory including the full path.

Author: Name

Usage:
  DirLister.py (-d <directory>)
  DirLister.py -h | --help
  DirLister.py --version

Options:
  -d <directory>     The top level directory you want to list files and directories from.
  -h --help          Show this screen.
  --version          Show version.
  """

import os
from docopt import docopt

class walking:
    def __init__(self, directory):
        self.directory = arguments['-d']

    def walk(self, directory):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.directory):
            for filename in files:
            print os.path.join(root, filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version= '1.0.0')
    print arguments
    if arguments['-d'] is None:
        print __doc__
        exit(0)
    else:
        walking.walk(directory)
```

**Original Non-Class Based Code** (working)

```
"""
Description:

This script is used to walk a directory and print out each filename and     directory including the full path.

Author: Name

Usage:
  DirLister.py (-d <directory>)
  DirLister.py -h | --help
  DirLister.py --version

Options:
  -d <directory>     The top level directory you want to list files and directories from.
  -h --help          Show this screen.
  --version          Show version.
  """

import os
from docopt import docopt

arguments = docopt(__doc__, version= '1.0.0')

def walk(dir):

   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for filename in files:
            print os.path.join(root, filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if arguments['-d'] is None:
        print __doc__
        exit(0)
    else:
        walk(arguments['-d'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten to post the error you get (since you say it's not working).

But indeed there are several issues. First, I'd call the class `Walking`.

Then in your `__init__` function, you try to access `arguments` which is neither a global variable nor an argument; you wanted to write:

```
def __init__(self, directory):
    self.directory = directory
```

But you also need to create an instance of your class in you `main`:

```
walking = Walking(arguments['-d'])
```

That assumes that the name of the class is `Walking` instead of `walking`. I advise you to look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the naming conventions.

The general idea is that the class is the type of an object, but not the object itself*, so the `class Walking:` block is basically defining a new kind of objects. And then you can create objects that are instances of this class. It's the same when you create a list: `mylist = list()` (but there are also other ways for lists like `mylist = [1, 2]`).

*It happens that most things in Python are objects, including classes, but they have obviously other methods and they have another base class.

Comment: Thanks @Francis Colas, That makes sense and is of course now working. I am going to make a few more scripts from scratch in a Class type fashion and see if I can get to grips with it. And I will take a look at the naming convention.